# NullPointerException when calling get function on array list

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have created a simple server and client application where when the server is running and a new client connects, a new user should be added to the "Bidder" class and their name should be outputted, in this case the name I am using is static and the user has not entered their name, which is "Jordan" in this case. So, upon client connection, a new bidder is added and this is then retrieved and outputted. However when outputting I receive a null pointer exception.

To retrieve the user's name:

```
final ArrayList<String> userNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Bidder bidder1 = null;
    final Bidder bidder = new Bidder(timeNow, client, bidder1, PORT);
    final Users user = new Users(itemOne,itemTwo);
    final ArrayList<ClientHandler> users =
                            new ArrayList<ClientHandler>();

    do
    {
        client = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("\nUser" + (user.getNumOfUsers()+1)
                                        + " has been accepted to the auction system.\n");
        System.out.println(bidder.getUserName());
        user.incUsers(users, client, handler);

    }while (true);
```

The bidder class:

```
class Bidder
{
    private ArrayList<Bidder> userNamesHandle;

    public Bidder(String name, Socket client, Bidder bidder, int i)
    {
        userNamesHandle = null;
    }
    public synchronized void createUser(ArrayList<Bidder> userList,final Socket
            client,Bidder handler)
    {
            String name = "Jordan";
            userList = userNamesHandle;
            int incrementUsers=0;

            for (final Bidder newBidder:userNamesHandle)
            {
                incrementUsers++;
            }
            userList.add(incrementUsers, handler = new Bidder(name, client, this, incrementUsers+1));
    }
    public synchronized Bidder getUserName()
    {
        int newNumOfUsers = 0;
        if(userNamesHandle != null)
        {
            for(final Bidder String:userNamesHandle)
            {
                newNumOfUsers++;
            }
        }
        return userNamesHandle.get(newNumOfUsers);
    }
}
```

I believe that the user's name is being added to the ArrayList however, I cannot retrieve it, and I am unsure why.

Comment: Look at the stacktrace. It tells you exactly in which line of which source file the `NullPointerException` happens. Something is `null` there. You get this exception, for example, when you try to call a method on a variable that is `null`.

Comment: Seems like it should be simple.  You've written some rather complex, unreadable code.  I see that you've declared userNamesHandle in the Bidder class, but it's never initialized anywhere.  If you dereference that you're guaranteed to get NPE.

Comment: Don't name variables which are the same as common classes e.g. `String`, or like any clasess

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `getUserName` method of class `Bidder`.

The statement `return userNamesHandle.get(newNumOfUsers);` will throw a `NullPointerException` if `userNamesHandle` is `null`.

In the constructor of the class, you initialize it to `null`.

Comment: okay however, if I then changed userList.add(incrementUsers, handler = new Bidder(name, client, this, incrementUsers+1)); to be userNamesHandle.add... this should then add a value to the array list, however this is not the case.

Comment: @DaveDavidson You should initialize `userNamesHandle` to something else than `null`. For example `userNamesHandle = new ArrayList<>();`. Frankly, your code is a bit of a mess. Why does `Bidder` have a constructor that takes 4 parameters that it doesn't use? Why does `Bidder` have an `ArrayList<Bidder>` member variable?